# Unity C# jumping coroutine creates floaty jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, coroutine

I'm trying to implement a variable jump in unity and found this tutorial from a few years ago where the last one (called "The Just Right") looks like the exact jump I want (I'm making a small endless runner).

Unfortunately I am having trouble figuring out how it works, as only part of the code is shown and since it's old no one is answering in the comments anymore.

I figured out what jumpButtonPressed and jumpTime are, but I am stuck on what jumpVector could mean.

**I have the jump working right now**, but it seems floatier than the example looks like so I don't think I've substituted jumpVector correctly.

This is the tutorial it's from: https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/DanielFineberg/20150825/244650/Designing_a_Jump_in_Unity.php

Here's what I have for it so far, the jump coroutine is basically the same as the one from the tutorial except instead of jumpVector I have Vector2.up + new Vector2(0, jumpDist). I can never seem to get jumps that feel nice and any advice would be good.

```cs
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 3.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpDist = 20.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float airTime = 0.5f;

    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    private bool jumping = false;
    private bool jumpBtnDown = false;

    private void Start() {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        //when space clicked, sets jumping and jumpBtnDown to true, starts jump coroutine
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && jumping == false) {
            Debug.Log("jump button pressed");
            //rigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpDist);
            jumping = true;
            jumpBtnDown = true;
            StartCoroutine(jump());
        }

        //if space let go, sets jumpBtnDown to false so the jump coroutine can end early
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) {
            Debug.Log("jump button released");
            jumpBtnDown = false;
        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        //basic movement for testing
        float move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(speed * move, rigidbody.velocity.y);
    }

    IEnumerator jump() {
        Debug.Log("jump coroutine started");
        rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        float timer = 0;

        while(jumpBtnDown == true && timer < airTime) {
            float percentJumpCompleted = timer / airTime;

            //this is the line that I don't think is working right and causing the jump to be floaty
            Vector2 jumpVectorThisFrame = Vector2.Lerp((Vector2.up + new Vector2(0, jumpDist)), Vector2.zero, percentJumpCompleted);
            rigidbody.AddForce(jumpVectorThisFrame);
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        jumping = false;
        Debug.Log("jump coroutine ended");
    }
}
```

(I'm not testing for if the player is grounded yet so jumping forever is something this code currently allows for, but I plan to add that in once I get the jump working nicely)

Comment: I think this might be related to you changing the velocity in `FixedUpdate()`. Can you try deleting your `FixedUpdate()`

Comment: I tested removing it to see if there was a difference and I can't see one, `FixedUpdate()` should only be affecting the horizontal movement as I don't change the y component of the velocity unless I'm looking at it wrong

Comment: There's a video on YouTube you might find helpful: [Better jumping in Unity with four lines of code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KiK0Aqtmzc)

Comment: Ah yeah that works so much better than the one I was trying, way less floaty thanks